# Rails: Conditional validation on association count (only if new associations created)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

We have a model `place` with a has_many relation to `place_attachements`. The maximum count of place_attachments should be validated based on a dynamic `place_attachments_limit` value set in the place model.

Basically, this can be done with a simple validation, but in our case we want to have an exception: The validation on attachments count should only apply on update and create actions on place_attachments, not on delete actions.

Explanation of this is, that if `place_attachements_limit` has decreased we want to keep all place attachments (even if limit is exceeded) but not to allow creating new ones unless total number has gone below the limit again.

Place attachments are created and destroyed via a nested form of place model.

How can we do this since we could not get any information of prior association count inside of our custom validation?

```
      class RespectQuotaValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
        attr_reader :record

        def initialize(options)
          super
        end

        # CAN WE SKIP THE FOLLOWING IN CASE OF PLACE ATTACHMENT DELETIONS?

        def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
          @record = record

          if !value.nil? && !record.map.nil?
            unless value_length <= record.place_attachments_limit
              record.errors.add(:base, I18n.t('errors.max_associations_per_place_exceeded'))
            end
          end
        end
      end
```